# Make input in program input value at website

Tags: input, javafx

I want a function in my JavaFX 2.0 program that takes user input and forwards it to a websites textfield, and then get the value the website returns. The website would be a site to check if the warranty for a spesific program is valid.

All the user would need to input is reg. ID and maybe program brand.

I'm just looking for ideas on how to do this, links or even code would be superb. I suspect it won't require that much code, but hey.. i've been surprised before!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation algorithm:

1. Load the warranty check page in the `WebView`.
2. Monitor the `webEngine.documentProperty` to check for when the load has finished.
3. When the load has finished, use `webEngine.executeScript` to set the text field to the
   required value and submit the form.
4. EITHER

   a.  monitor the `webEngine.documentProperty` some more, and, when the document has loaded, inspect the document (using either JavaScript or Java) to see if the warranty is valid.

   OR

   b. change the resultant warranty display page to call back into Java and notify your app of the warranty status.

---

*Some background info*

If you have control over the website page contents, then your implementation may turn out easier.  But I think you should still be able to get the result you want without modifying the website.

There were some additions to the recent JavaFX 2.1 release to facilitate callbacks from Javascript to Java.  The [webview documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) you want to read is the sections "Processing JavaScript Commands" using the `webEngine.executeScript` method and "Making Upcalls from JavaScript to JavaFX" using `JSObject.setMember`.

You might want to also take a look at a [Sample DatePicker for JavaFX using jQuery UI](https://gist.github.com/1422815) example I wrote.  It demonstrates various methods for loading html into a `WebView`, invoking functions on the `WebView` from Java and getting the results of user interactions with the `WebView` back into Java.  Not exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps the ideas in it may help.

Another option you have is just to:

1. Accept the registration id in a JavaFX control.
2. Create a `java.net.URL` and post to the webserver from your java app directly without using a `WebView`.
3. Parse the response from the webserver to extract out whether the warranty is valid.

This is the approach I might take for such a task - eliminating the use of WebView completely.